# Android in-app purchase multiple subscriptions

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm implementing the in-app purchase lib by google and i have a question about subscriptions :

- is there possible to have 2 or more subscriptions active and renewable ?

I used the following code where i know i have subscribe to two items:

```
Purchase.PurchasesResult result = mBillingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);
if (result!=null && result.getPurchasesList()!=null && result.getPurchasesList().size()>0) {

        Toast.makeText(context,"SUB 1: "+result.getPurchasesList().get(0).getSku()+"/"+result.getPurchasesList().get(0).isAutoRenewing(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(context,"SUB 2: "+result.getPurchasesList().get(1).getSku()+"/"+result.getPurchasesList().get(1).isAutoRenewing(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
```

The result for both is true on :

```
result.getPurchasesList().get(0).isAutoRenewing()
result.getPurchasesList().get(1).isAutoRenewing()
```

In the first place i substribe for the first and then for the second. My expectation was to recive above only for the second one TRUE for isAutoRenewing()

I did not use upgrade sintax. So technically : is there possible to have 2 active subs ?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to have multiple active subscriptions. Upgrade/downgrade from different subscriptions isn't by default. Depending on the methods you use, you have to specify which subscriptions to replace if you only want one active subscription at a time.